# Webcam stretched when canvas size fixed p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to do three things:

1. Aspect ratio 16:9
2. Triangle in centre
3. Webcam on top

I am trying to make it so that different computers can have a triangle in the same position with the total canvas at 16:9, but what currently happens is that it is stretching the video input.

Any ideas?

https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/870510

```
var video;

function setup() {
createCanvas(1100, 619);
background(255);
video = createCapture(VIDEO);
video.size(1100,619); 
video.hide();
}

function draw() {
image(video,0,0,width,height); 
strokeWeight(4);
line(400, 400, 550, 150);
line(550, 150, 700, 400);
line(700, 400, 400, 400);     
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need to get window `width` and then you can calculate the canvas `height` with 16:9 aspect ratio

```
var video;

var h, w;

function setup() {
   // get window width
   w = window.innerWidth;
   // calculate canvas height
   h = (w * 9) / 16;
   // create canvas
   createCanvas(w, h);
   background(255);
   video = createCapture(VIDEO);
   // get video scaling ratio
   var ratio = h / video.height;
   // recalculate video width
   var video_w = video.width * ratio;
   video.size(video_w, h); 
   video.hide(); 
}
```

and then to make the triangle in center, we can calculate the center by dividing `height` and `width` by `2`

```
function draw() {
   // calculate center
   var cx = w / 2;
   var cy = h / 2;
   // set the triangle width
   var width = 150;
   var half_width = width / 2;
   // calculate the triangle height using pythagoras theorm
   var height = Math.sqrt(width * width - half_width * half_width);
   var half_height = height / 2;
   // draw bottom of the triangle
   line(cx - half_width, cy + half_height, cx + half_width, cy + half_height);
   // draw left of the triangle
   line(cx - half_width, cy + half_height, cx, cy - half_height);
   // draw right of the triangle
   line(cx, cy - half_height, cx + half_width, cy + half_height);
}
```

Comment: Surya you are the best! Thank you for helping get a step further, but by putting the canvas as 16:9 it still stretches the video: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/877883. I am trying to use the video as the dough and the 16:9 as the cookie-cutter that takes from the webcam, currently is still takes the webcam input and stretches it to be 16:9.

Comment: I update the code, it will calculate video size but still in its aspect ratio

Comment: Thanks for your help Surya but there is no webcam on this? I think you are missing a line like:   image(video,0,0,w,h); to display the webcam? :(